# webpack-dev-server nothing renders

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to add `webpack-dev-server` to my React app, however when I open localhost:8080 and look in the console, the request for `js/bundle.js` returned a 404 error.

Here is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/app/js/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}dist/app/js`,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          // {
          //   loader: "react-hot-loader"
          // },
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
              presets: ["react", "es2015"],
              plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: `${__dirname}/dist/app/`,
    publicPath: `${__dirname}/dist/app/js/`
  }
};
```

Here is dist/app/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-container"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The console outputs this:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /private/var/www/mysite.com/dist/app/back/js/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /private/var/www/mysite.com/dist/app/
```

Looking in `js/` there is no `bundle.js`, but it's my understanding that this is correct, as `webpack-dev-server` creates the file only in memory.

Why am I getting a 404... what am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the script src to just bundle.js removing the js/

Comment: Thanks I tried that but still 404.

Comment: It works after removing the `publicPath` property.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the update